# Can I include an icon to the highlighted item for PrimeNG dropdown?

Tags: html, css, dropdown, primeng

I'm trying to add a check icon for when an item is selected for PrimeNG dropdown. I managed to make it show for all items, but I only want it to show for the item selected. Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

```html
<label for="">Status</label>
<br>
<p-dropdown [options]="status" [(ngModel)]="selectedStatus" [style]="dStyle" >
    <ng-template let-car pTemplate="item">
        <div class="ui-helper-clearfix" style="position: relative;height: 25px;">
            <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-top:5px;"></i>
            <div style="font-size:14px;display: inline-block;margin-top:4px;padding-left: 20px;">{{car.label}}</div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-dropdown>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add an *ngIf on your icon and set it to see if the "car" is equal to your selectedStatus

http://plnkr.co/edit/L5Us5L8UptothCP1SCKU?p=preview

```
<p-dropdown [options]="cars" [(ngModel)]="selectedCar" [style]="dStyle" >
    <ng-template let-car pTemplate="item">
        <div class="ui-helper-clearfix" style="position: relative;height: 25px;">
            <i *ngIf="selectedCar === car.value" class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-top:5px;"></i>
            <div style="font-size:14px;display: inline-block;margin-top:4px;padding-left: 20px;">{{car.label}}</div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-dropdown>
```

Comment: For some reason, now the dropdown stopped working when I attempted that.

Comment: You can see from the plnkr that it clearly works.  You probably have to modify the variables based on your individual code from inside your component.ts

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that.